# Create a personal Microsoft Account on a hosted O365 domain

Tags: microsoft-account

I am trying to create a personal Microsoft account on a hosted Office 365 domain. When I try and do it, I get an error that you can't create a personal Microsoft account on a school/work domain.

I am intentionally trying to do this because I have consolidated all of my various email addresses and don't want to create another one.

Alternatively, can I create an account to use with Xbox using a "work" O365 domain?

The irony in this is that the domain is neither work/school, it's my personal domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I'm gathering that you've gone from sam@Gmail, Yahoo, AOL, btinternet, Hotmail, sharklazers etc into sam@sam.com?

Now you have just set up 365, for you sam@sam.com account... and you now want to join Xbox Live.

As far as I know (someone correct me if I'm wrong), the 365 and personal accounts are separate within the Microsoft land, as they have different login pages, and are for different services.

The way I would get around this is by creating a new Microsoft (personal) account, but use your 365 account email as the email instead of creating a new account, with an email address.

This can be done by going to [xbox.com](https://xbox.com), click "Create One!", then enter your sam@sam.com email as the email.

Then you've got the Personal Account without the new email...

Also, there is a [post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Cleaning-up-the-AzureAD-and-Microsoft-account-overlap/ba-p/245105) explaining that Microsoft has changed it so 365 domain users can't create a personal account.

"If you're an app developer, you should probably support both personal and work accounts from Microsoft." - [source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Cleaning-up-the-AzureAD-and-Microsoft-account-overlap/ba-p/245105)

They do know it is a need for many people to complete their jobs, so they are allowing it and from what I infer it is a setting that (you) as the IT Admin, can set in AD, to allow the creation of personal accounts.

(source, I know many people who use this with Gmail accounts)